# Best way to manage Excel-PPT automations?

Tags: excel, automation, powerpoint

I frequently come across tasks where I have to automate, e.g. a few graphs and tables in PPT using data in Excel. Therefore, the macros also reside within Excel.

**What do you think is the best / most-effective / easiest to build & manage approach for this?**

Below are some examples of what I do:

**1) Relatively easier to build macro, impossible to make changes in PPT.**

```
A PPT template is saved in (e.g.) same folder as the Excel model. 
Excel-Macros update the data charts & tables in Excel and 
then copy them as pictures into the PPT template, save PPT as a new file for use.
```

**2) Relatively tedious to build macros, possible & easy to make changes in PPT.**

```
PPT template saved in a folder. 
Excel-Macros open Excel behind each graph one by one and 
update the data in those chart-excels. 
Similarly, Excel-Macros go through PPT tables cell by cell 
and update the data in PPT tables.
```

This process is slow and risky because Excel-Macros can lose track of open chart-Excel files due to various reasons.

**3) Unpredictable?**

```
Copy paste Excel file's graphs into the PPT template file 
which makes PPT graphs connected to Excel data, much easier to update.
```

But this is a bit unpredictable about what would break the link between both and PPT will start showing errors. Also, no way to connect a PPT table to Excel.

Comment: This question does not seem to meet the StackOverflow standards. However, I prefer something similar to your first option. I create a PPT template with named areas, shapes and objects. Next, my Excel macro analyzes the PPT and creates a table with all relevant PPT names. This table can be linked to given data via Excel formula. It can handle text, colors, images and charts - which are stored as images. Whenever data changes, I can run the macro to insert/add/update the PPT. On the other hand, the PPT can still be edited and changed - except the charts.

Comment: I stay away from option #2 as chart areas tend to change their size whenever, the excel data source is changes. At least it did in older Office versions. This resulted in unprofessional layouts.